# import('my-module') not working when using variable

Tags: webpack

```js
import('my-module')
```

is working while

```js
const src = 'my-module';
import(src);
```

doesn't work.

Throws error from `webpackEmptyAsyncContext`.

```js
"webpack": "^5.18.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.4.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
```

I have deleted `npm_modules` and `package-lock.json`

Also added

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'my-module': './my-module.ts'
    }
}
```

Also, the `import('my-module')` command doesn't work on web workers. Unfortunately I'm using `importScripts` instead in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

what's the reason for using variables for an import? If you would like to use something like dependency injections there are better approaches.

Comment: I want to create a function that imports a module whether I'm running in a web worker or not.
For web workers I have to use `self.importScripts` and for a window I can use the regular `import`.